# Map path between two points Ionic 2 offline

Tags: google-maps, location, ionic2, leaflet

How to get a path offline between two points using my actual location ?

Is there a way to get it ? i read there is a library called Leaflet which can run offfline.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: didn't actually find enough documentation, about offline mapping + Leaflet.
I'm kind of new to Ionic2

Answer (score 0):

You might use de geolocalization native plugin and some javascript to paint a line between two points. I don't know about leaflet, but opne layers is a good tool to create offline maps.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/ .

http://openlayers.org/

I'm too trying to do something with offline map in ionic. Please post whatever you do with this resorcer and I'll do the same :)

Comment: I managed to get my actual location, my actual problem is to get the path between my location and a marker which i select, i think in this case we need to use Mapbox to calculate the distance.